# How to find which dirction to move in a 3D space

Tags: java, path-finding

In my game you are controlling a person walking(X and Y) and they can:

```
Rotate view - -180 to +180
Move a direction - Forward, Backwards, Left, Right.
```

I want the Move to get closer to a goal position by using the Forward, Backward, Left and Right.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/OcDr1.png

The player can be looking anywhere on the -180 to 180 rotation and the direction of the Forward, Backward, Left and Right is changed by Rotation.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: http://www.red3d.com/cwr/steer/ ?

Answer (score 2):

So your problem is: You have 4 different directions (vectors) and you want to make a linear combination of them, to reach some point "x". Observation 1: You can make that in 2D using only 2 directions (vectors), (for math people: marix rank is 2).

So first, choose 2 linearly independent vectors (Forward - (1,0), Right - (0,1)) and rotate them with your rotation (multiply with [rotation matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix)).

Then, all you have to do is solve the system of 2 linear equations with 2 variables. You can probably write that in 1 line of code.

Another way is to rotate your point "x" with negative rotation, then you will get the solution straight away.

Comment: The point was that you can't control the rotation of the player only the movement.